# Query to include first record and last record for show only one output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I retrieves the Validfrom is MIN and Validto is MAX, only show the last max record?

```
select *
from Employee
where the Staff ID = A123456
```

*Current Result*

```
Staff ID, Staff Full Name, Staff English Name, Position, Division, Department, Section, VALIDFROM, VALIDTO    
A123456,Chan Tai Man,Peter Chan,CLERK,MARKETING,SUPPORT SERVICES,NONE,**2000-01-01 00:00:00.000**,2014-12-31 23:59:59.000    
A123456,Chan Tai Man,Peter Chan,SUPERVISOR,MARKETING,SUPPORT SERVICES,NONE,2005-01-01 00:00:00.000,2010-12-31 23:59:59.000    
**A123456,Chan Tai Man,Peter Chan,MANAGER,MARKETING,SUPPORT SERVICES,NONE**,2011-01-01 00:00:00.000,**2016-12-31 23:59:59.000**
```

*Expected Result from BOLD above*

```
Staff ID,Staff Full Name,Staff English Name,Position,Division,Department,Section,VALIDFROM,VALIDTO    
A123456,Chan Tai Man,Peter Chan,MANAGER,MARKETING,SUPPORT SERVICES,NONE,2000-01-01 00:00:00.000,2016-12-31 23:59:59.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you wanted the `MIN()` for `VALIDFROM` but the rest of columns are from the row where `VALIDTO` is latest

`FIRST_VALUE(VALIDFROM)` gives you the first value / min of `VALIDFROM`

`ROW_NUMBER()...` gives you the row with latest `VALIDTO`

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
           SELECT *,
                  MIN_VALIDFROM = FIRST_VALUE(VALIDFROM) OVER (PARTITION BY [STAFF ID]
                                                                   ORDER BY VALIDFROM),
                  RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [STAFF ID] 
                                              ORDER BY VALIDTO DESC)
           FROM   Employee
       ) e
WHERE  e.RN = 1
AND    e.[Staff ID] = 'A123456'
```